# C# Razor View Error - Braces Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Apologies, if this is very easy for some of you (if not everyone). I am a newbie in Razor view, so your help and support is highly appreciated.

I am receiving the following error:

> } expected

in the Line 1. Here: @model ForExample.Models.DataClass

My Razor code:

```
@model ForExample.Models.DataClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit: " + @Model.Title;
}

@if(Model != null)
{

     if (@ViewBag.Message != "")
     {      
                var messageString = @ViewBag.Message;

                if (messageString.Contains("Successfully"))
                {
                    <h3 style="color:green;">@ViewBag.Message</h3>
                }
                if(!messageString.Contains("Successfully"))
                {
                    <h3 style="color:red;">@ViewBag.Message</h3>
                }
     }

    <div>
        <form method="post">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Title)</h4>
            <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" class="form-control" value="@Model.Title" />
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Tags)</h4>
            <input type="text" id="Tags" name="Tags" class="form-control" value="@Model.Tags" />
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Description)</h4>
            <textarea id="Description" name="Description" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="100">@Model.Description</textarea><br />
            <button value="Example" id="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> Save Changes </button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if (@ViewBag.Message != "") should be if (ViewBag.Message != "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify the switch to razor (`@` character) after certain constructs

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    if (@ViewBag.Message != "") -> (1)
    {      
        var messageString = @ViewBag.Message;  -> (2)

        if (messageString.Contains("Successfully")) -> (3)
                <h3 style="color:green;">@ViewBag.Message</h3> -> (4)
```

After the first `@if`, you are in Razor markup, hence:

1. You don't need that `@`, because you are still in Razor
2. Same as point 1
3. As you can see, you are still in Razor (otherwise, that would be invalid `HTML`)
4. Here you do need `@` because you moved to `HTML`

So, your View fixed should look like this:

```
@model ForExample.Models.DataClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit: " + Model.Title;
}

@if(Model != null)
{
    string message = ViewBag.Message as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {      
        if (message.Contains("Successfully"))
        {
            <h3 style="color:green;">@message</h3>
        }
        else
        {
            <h3 style="color:red;">@message</h3>
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to check why you first use `Model.Title` and lines after you check `Model != null`.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var messageString = @ViewBag.Message;
```

is already inside a code block (opened by the `if` condition statement). So you do not need the extra `@`.

The extra verbatim `@` is the cause for your error. Remove that and everything should work fine.

You probably want do a null instead of checking against empty string for `iewBag.Message`. Calling `Contains` method on  the value of `ViewBag.Message` when it is `NULL` will throw you an exception (***Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference***)

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {      
        var messageString = ViewBag.Message;

        if (messageString.Contains("Successfully"))
        {
            <h3 style="color:green;">@messageString</h3>
        }
        if(!messageString.Contains("Successfully"))
        {
            <h3 style="color:red;">@messageString</h3>
        }
    }
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Title)</h4>
            <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" class="form-control" value="@Model.Title" />
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Tags)</h4>
            <input type="text" id="Tags" name="Tags" class="form-control" value="@Model.Tags" />
            <h4>@Html.LabelFor(ex => ex.Description)</h4>
            <textarea id="Description" name="Description" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="100">@Model.Description</textarea><br />
            <button value="Example" id="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> Save Changes </button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

I also noticed, you are creating input elements and setting the value attribute value from the properties of the model.  You may consider the `Html.TextBoxFor` helper method, which will generate the same for you

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Title,new { @class="form-control"})
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, there's a `@Model.Title;` at the top where the `@` is not valid

Comment: I 99% sure that, that code will still work as it, is because it is in a separate code block.  Also No need of null check as string concatenation will take care of that as we have at least one valid string (`Edit:`) in that expression

Comment: Now i am 100 % sure it works. I just verified it locally :)

Comment: That's what I was gonna do. I was pretty sure that VS the other complained that I put a `@` inside a `@{ }`

Comment: Yea, VS should give a warning., but the code will not crash